# Using pattern matching and recursion in Elixir to split the list

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, elixir

I am new in Elixir and new in programming, especially functional programming (less than 1 year experience in Ruby and RoR). For the moment I am reading "Programming Elixir" by Dave Thomas. And I am completely stuck with one problem from the Lists and Recursion theme.

Dave asking to "implement the following Enum functions using no library functions or list comprehensions: ...split ..."

The original function is [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Enum.html#split/2).

I solve the problem with rather long, probably not too optimal (and seems to me partially disobeying Dave's restrictions) way:

```
def split(list, count) do
  if count < 0, do: count = len(list) + count
  list1 = filter1(list, count)
  list2 = list -- list1
  # list2 = filter2(list, list1)
  { list1, list2 }
end

def len([]), do: 0
def len([ _head | tail ]), do: 1 + len(tail)

defp filter1([], _count), do: []
defp filter1([ head | tail], count) do
  if count > 0 do
    [ head | filter1(tail, count - 1) ]
  else
    filter1(tail, count - 1)
  end
end
```

Browsing through the [page](https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/322/topics/Exercise:%20ListsAndRecursion-5) with Dave's and other readers solutions I find out pattern which was used by 2 or 3 readers:

```
def split([head | tail], count) when count > 0 do
  {left, right} = split(tail, count-1)
  {[head | left], right}
end
def split(list, _count), do: {[], list}
```

This code seems to me rather elegant, but I can not understand how it works.
I mean I've tried to comprehend what happening step by step and I failed.

I can imagine what happening in my `filter1` recursive function. List is forming like this: `[ head_1 | ... head_n | filter1(tail_n, count - n) ]`

But I can't understand why `{ left, right }` tuple is matching the recursive call for the function. What should match to the `left` and what to the `right`? How this recursion works?...

(The meaning of the second line (of the function) is also not clear for me but I think this is strictly connected with the first question.)

**UPD:**

Thanks to @Josh Petitt, @tkowal and @CodyPoll I think I moved forward in my comprehension of the case.

Now I am thinking about the recursion-matching pattern discussed in this "pyramidal way":

```
1  split([1, 2, 3], 2)
2    {left, right} = split([2, 3], 1)
3    {[1 | left], right}
4      {left, right} = split([3], 0)
5      {[1 | [2 | left]], right}
6    {[1 | [2 | []]], [3]}
7  {[1 ,2], [3]}
```

- *First step (line 1):* call the function.
- *Second step (lines 2, 3):* match `{left, right}` tuple to the recursive function call and return `{[1 | left], right}` tuple
- *Third step (lines 4, 5):* match `{left, right}` tuple to the next recursive call and return `{[1 | [2 | left]], right}` tuple
- *Fourth step (line 6):* since `split([3], 0)` matching the second clause we get `{left, right} = {[], [3]}` at this point and we can no replace `left` and `right` variables in the line 5 with [] and [3] accordingly
- *Fifth step (line 7):* "pipes" do their job and return the list to finally match the `left` variable

What I still don't understand is how folks come to this type of solution? (Probably experience with both pattern matching and recursion.)

And another thing bothers me. If we take line 3 for example, it is a "return" which contains two variables. But no values was actually matched to this variables. According to my scheme this variables only match their values in line 7.

How Elixir deal with this?
Is it some implicit `nil` matching? 
Or I am taking the process wrong and there is no actual return until the final step?

Comment: Keep in mind that while this code _is_ elegant, it doesn't actually replicate the behavior of `Enum.split` when `count` is a negative number, or when count is larger than the length of the list.

Comment: Thank you @CodyPoll ! Yep... I am aware that this part of the code only implement part of the original `Enum.split` behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion is sometimes very difficult to understand just looking at the code. Mentally tracking what is put on the stack and what and when it is retrieved can exhaust our working memory very quickly. It can be useful to draw the path of every passage in the hierarchy of the recursion tree, and this is what I've done to try to answer to your question.

To understand how things work in this example, first of all we have to recognize the existence of two distinct stages in the Clause 1, the first stage is the code executed before the recursion, the second stage is the code that will be executed after it.

(to better explain the flow, I've added some variables to the original code)

```
# Clause 1
def split(in_list, count) when count > 0 do
  # FIRST STAGE
  [head | tail] = in_list

  # RECURSION
  result = split(tail, count - 1)

  # SECOND STAGE
  {left, right} = result 
  return = {[head | left], right}
end

#Clause 2
def split(list, _count), do: return = {[], list}
```

Now, before continue to reading, please look at the code and try to answer to these questions:

- after how many iterations of the first block the `result` variable will be bound for the first time ?
- How many times the recursion `split(tail, count - 1)` will be called inside Clause 1 ?
- How many times the Clause 2 `split(list, _count)` will be called?
- What is the role of the Clause 2 ?

And now compare your answers looking at this schema that show every passage and its hierarchy:

(as an example, we split the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` after its third element  to obtain the tuple `{[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]}`)

```
split([1,2,3,4,5], 3)

> FIRST STAGE of CLAUSE 1 / ITERATION 1 called as: split( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3 ):
  Got 'head'=1, 'tail'=[2, 3, 4, 5], 'count'=3
  now I'm going to iterate passing the tail [2, 3, 4, 5],
  Clause 1 will match as the counter is still > 0
     > FIRST STAGE of CLAUSE 1 / ITERATION 2 called as: split( [2, 3, 4, 5], 2 ):
       Got 'head'=2, 'tail'=[3, 4, 5], 'count'=2
       now I'm going to iterate passing the tail [3, 4, 5],
       Clause 1 will match as the counter is still > 0
          > FIRST STAGE of CLAUSE 1 / ITERATION 3 called as: split( [3, 4, 5], 1 ):
            Got 'head'=3, 'tail'=[4, 5], 'count'=1
            Now the counter is 0 so I've reached the split point,
            and the Clause 2 instead of Clause 1 will match at the next iteration

> Greetings from CLAUSE 2 :-), got [4, 5], returning {[], [4, 5]}

          < Im BACK to the SECOND STAGE of ITERATION 3
            got result from CLAUSE 2: {[], [4, 5]}
            {left, right} = {[], [4, 5]}
            Now I'm build the return value as {[head | left], right},
            prepending 'head' (now is 3) to the previous value
            of 'left' (now is []) at each iteration,
            'right' instead is always [4, 5].
            So I'm returning {[3], [4, 5]} to iteration 2
     < Im BACK to the SECOND STAGE of ITERATION 2
       got result from previous Clause 1 / Iteration 3, : {[3], [4, 5]}
       {left, right} = {[3], [4, 5]}
       Now I'm build the return value as {[head | left], right},
       prepending 'head' (now is 2) to the previous value
       of 'left' (now is [3]) at each iteration,
       'right' instead is always [4, 5].
       So I'm returning {[2, 3], [4, 5]} to iteration 1
< Im BACK to the SECOND STAGE of ITERATION 1
  got result from previous Clause 1 / Iteration 2, : {[2, 3], [4, 5]}
  {left, right} = {[2, 3], [4, 5]}
  Now I'm build the return value as {[head | left], right},
  prepending 'head' (now is 1) to the previous value
  of 'left' (now is [2, 3]) at each iteration,
  'right' instead is always [4, 5].
  And my final return is at least: {[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]}
{[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]}
```

In the schema, the *beginning* of every iteration is marked with

```
> FIRST STAGE of CLAUSE 1 / ITERATION n called as: ...
```

meanwhile the beginning of the *continuation* of the iteration is marked as

```
< I'm BACK to the SECOND STAGE of ITERATION n
```

Now we can clearly see that:

- the first block is iterated three times;
- the Clause 2 is called just ONE time;
- second block is iterated three times, the first time it    receive the result from the Clause 2, the remaining times from Clause    1;
- the result of Clause 2 contains the right portion of the splitted    list, computed in third iteration of Clause 1.

So, what is the role for Clause 2? It is a trick, a way to pass back, down to the continuation of the iterations, the otherwise inaccessible value of the right part of the splitted list.

Here it is a step-by-step explanation of the code:

In the *first stage*  the value of the first parameter of the function, the variable I've called `in_list`, is decomposed in its `head` and `tail` components:

```
# FIRST STAGE
[head | tail] = in_list
```

then the `head` is pushed on the stack and the `tail` and the update `counter` are passed to the recursion:

```
result = split(tail, count - 1)
```

after `count` iterations, all the left-splitted elements are on the stack, and all the right-splitted elements are packed in the `tail`. The the Clause 2 is now called.

After the Clause 2 call, the recursion continue with the second stage, where the `result` variable is bound to the two (partially) splitted list returned by the previous `split/2` iteration.

Now, at every iteration, we extract the left and right lists fron the result:

{left, right} = result

and add to the `left` the `head` popped from the stack ( that was computed in the first stage), returning the result to the caller:

```
return = {[head | left], right}
```

so at every iteration the left part grows 'till the final value.

The first `result` is returned by the Clause 2, matched when the iterations had reached the split point i.e. when `count = 0`. (Clause 2 will  fire just one time). All the subsequent `result`s will be returned by the folded second stages of the Clause 1 iterations.

This is the code to print the above schema:

```
def split(in_list, count), do: split(in_list, count, 1)

    # Clause 1
    def split(in_list=[head | tail], count, iteration) when count > 0 do
      offset = String.duplicate " ", 5 * (iteration - 1)
      IO.puts offset <> "> FIRST STAGE of CLAUSE 1 / ITERATION #{inspect iteration} called as: split( #{inspect in_list}, #{inspect(count)} ):"
      IO.puts offset <> "  Got 'head'=#{inspect head}, 'tail'=#{inspect tail}, 'count'=#{inspect count}"
      if (count - 1) > 0 do
        IO.puts offset <> "  now I'm going to iterate passing the tail #{inspect(tail)},"
        IO.puts offset <> "  Clause 1 will match as the counter is still > 0"
      else
        IO.puts offset <> "  Now the counter is 0 so I've reached the split point,"
        IO.puts offset <> "  and the Clause 2 instead of Clause 1 will match at the next iteration"
      end

      result = split(tail, count-1, iteration + 1)

      IO.puts offset <> "< Im BACK to the SECOND STAGE of ITERATION #{inspect(iteration)}"
      if (count - 1) == 0 do
        IO.puts offset <> "  got result from CLAUSE 2: #{inspect result}"
      else
        IO.puts offset <> "  got result from previous Clause 1 / Iteration #{iteration + 1}, : #{inspect result}"
      end
      IO.puts offset <> "  {left, right} = #{inspect result}"
      {left, right} = result
      IO.puts offset <> "  Now I'm build the return value as {[head | left], right},"
      IO.puts offset <> "  prepending 'head' (now is #{inspect head}) to the previous value"
      IO.puts offset <> "  of 'left' (now is #{inspect left}) at each iteration,"
      IO.puts offset <> "  'right' instead is always #{inspect right}."
      return = {[head | left], right}
      if (iteration > 1) do
        IO.puts offset <> "  So I'm returning #{inspect return} to iteration #{inspect(iteration - 1)}"
      else
        IO.puts offset <> "  And my final return is at least: #{inspect return} "
      end
      return
    end

    # Clause 2
    def split(list, _count, _iteration) do
      IO.puts ""
      IO.puts "> Greetings from CLAUSE 2 :-), got #{inspect(list)}, returning #{inspect({[], list})}"
      IO.puts ""
      {[], list}
    end
```

Hope this can help to clarify a little bit the strategy adopted and the internal recursion mechanism.

(my English is not very good, hope someone can fix this text)

Comment: Thank you very much @Guido, your answer is very comprehensive (I can not even imagine what time it could take to prepare an answer like this). Now I see the full picture. Your SCHEMA is just what I was looking for. Sorry for so late reaction from my side, I was out of Elixir learning for some time.

Comment: You're welcome @max.underthesun . It took some time, but it was worth because recursion can be an ugly thing without a clear description of its internal mechanism. This answer serves as a reminder for me too.

Answer (score 4):

```
# the first element is head, the tail is the rest of the list
# count must be greater than 0 to match
def split([head | tail], count) when count > 0 do

  # recursively call passing in tail and decrementing the count
  # it will match a two element tuple
  {left, right} = split(tail, count-1)

  # return a two element tuple containing
  # the head, concatenated with the left element
  # and the right (i.e. the rest of the list)
  {[head | left], right}

end

# this is for when count is <= 0
# return a two element tuple with an empty array the rest of the list
# do not recurse
def split(list, _count), do: {[], list}
```

I've added some comments to the code above.
The net effect is that the head of the list is continually stripped off and concatenated with the "left" list until count is decremented to 0.  At that point you are have a two lists returned as a tuple.

Comment: Thanks @Josh Petitt ! The thing is that I understand (or think I am understand) every part of your comments, and all this was clear for me from the beginning. But I could not catch why  "it will match a two element tuple"... this was my original question actually. As I mentioned I can imagine  how `[ head | filter1(tail, count - 1) ]`  looks like in recursion. But I still couldn't see the `{left, right} = split(tail, count-1)` model.

Comment: it matches a two-element tuple because both forms of the function return a two element tuple :-)

Comment: The bottom split clause returns `{[], list}`, and the top returns `{list, right}`.  Since in elixir, you can do `{a, b} = {1, 2}`. Now `a == 1 && b == 2`, `{left, right}` will match against whatever is returned by the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

The code is tricky, because it is not tail recursive, so it is not a loop and it remembers O(n) calls.

Lets try to analyze on a simple example where indent indicates level of recursion:

```
split([1,2,3], 2) ->
#head = 1, tail = [2,3], count = 2
{left, right} = split([2,3], 1) -> #this is the recursive call
  #head = 2, tail = [3], count = 1
  {left, right} = split([3], 0)    #this call returns immediately, because it matches second clause
  {left, right} = {[], [3]} #in this call
  #what we have now is second list in place, we need to reassemble the first one from what we remember in recursive calls
  #head still equals 2, left = [], right = [3]
  {[head | left], right} = {[2], [3]} #this is what we return to higher call
#head = 1, left = [2], right = [3]
{[head | left], right} = {[1,2], [3]}
```

So the pattern is that you disassemble the list and remember its elements in recursion and then reassemble it. The simplest case for such pattern is:

```
def identity([]) -> []
def identity([head | tail]) do
  # spot 1
  new_tail = identity(tail)
  # spot 2
  [head | tail]
end
```

This function does nothing to the original list. It only traverses all elements. To understand the pattern, guess what happen when you place `IO.puts head` in spot 1 and spot 2.

Then try to modify it traverse only count of elements and then you will see how close you are to the `split` implementation.

Comment: Thank you @tkowal. May be this scheme will help me, but not yet. I will try to meditate on the answers given for some time. Hope I'll find the light :)